# App Transport Security key NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia is not working as expected on iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

As per Apple guide, the value of `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key is ignored if `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMediaContent` key is present in app’s `Info.plist` file. But I have observed that this is not happening. So anyone has observed the same? I have tried this on `iOS 10 beta 7` with `Xcode 8` beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have have observed the same. It seems a bug in iOS 10 beta 7. Hope it will work as mentioned in documentation in next release.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work in a way you expect.

*...only for loading media that are **already encrypted**...* - [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW60)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in apple documentation
The right name of the tag is NSAllowsArbitraryLoads**For**Media
I had a chat with someone from apple support.
he asked me to open a bug about this issue.
Apple Bugid is **29268036** 
Apple bug title is "**NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia key is not working on NSAppTransportSecurity**"
Apple fixed the documentation.
You can see now the right documentation at
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33
After i changed my plist to the right key it worked for me.
I check it on ipad air 2 with ios 10.2 beta 2